# Calling a variable of one Class in an other Class

Tags: java, class, variables

I have some problems by calling a Variable of a separate .java Class in an other .java class.

I tried to declare the Variables in the Variables.java file and use the **same** two variables in the other .java file. But it doesn't work.

**Variables.java:**

```
package de.cfe.base;

public class Variables {
    public static int int1;
    public static int int2;

}
```

and

**CallingTheVariables.java:**

```
package de.cfe.base;

public class CallingTheVariables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int1 = 1;
        int2 = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you say just `int1` and `int2`, Java assumes that they are defined already and in scope in the class.  But they aren't defined in `CallingTheVariables`.  You must qualify your reference with the class on which they're defined:

```
Variables.int1 = 1;
Variables.int2 = 10;
```

An advanced alternative is the [*static import*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) (scroll down in that page).  In the class to reference the variables, place this above the class:

```
import static de.cfe.base.Variables.*;
```

Then you could refer to the variables with their simple names as you have it already:

```
int1 = 1;
int2 = 10;
```

Comment: Static imports are not recommended. From the java docs: *Use static import very sparingly. Overusing static import can result in code that is difficult to read and maintain, because readers of the code won't know which class defines a particular static object. Used properly, static import makes code more readable by removing class name repetition.*

Comment: @Troubleshoot That is a good addition to any text introducing static imports.  True, it can be confusing when misused, but in this case, performing one static import on one class should be okay.

Comment: In this case using a static import isn't needed. There are only two static variables.

Comment: @Troubleshoot Static imports are never needed.  The main purpose, as you have already quoted, is to improve readability by removing class name repetition.  I don't think I'd recommend using it here either, but it is an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Variables.int1 = 1;
Variables.int2 = 10;
```

`int1` and `int2` "belong" to `Variables`, so you can only access them through `Variables`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CallingTheVariables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Variables.int1 = 1;
        Variables.int2 = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
Variables.int1 = 1;
Variables.int2 = 10;
```

or you can do a [static import.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

```
import static de.cfe.base.Variables.*;
```

The static import construct allows unqualified access to static members without inheriting from the type containing the static members. Instead, the program imports the members, either individually:

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
```

or en masse:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

> **when should you use static import?**
>
> Very sparingly! Only use it when you'd otherwise be tempted to declare
> local copies of constants, or to abuse inheritance (the Constant
> Interface Antipattern). In other words, use it when you require
> frequent access to static members from one or two classes. If you
> overuse the static import feature, it can make your program unreadable
> and unmaintainable, polluting its namespace with all the static
> members you import. Readers of your code (including you, a few months
> after you wrote it) will not know which class a static member comes
> from. Importing all of the static members from a class can be
> particularly harmful to readability;
>
> **if you need only one or two members, import them individually. Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable, by
> removing the boilerplate of repetition of class names.**

Comment: Static imports are not recommended. From the java docs: *Use static import very sparingly. Overusing static import can result in code that is difficult to read and maintain, because readers of the code won't know which class defines a particular static object. Used properly, static import makes code more readable by removing class name repetition.*

Comment: @Troubleshoot `if you need only one or two members, import them individually. Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable, by removing the boilerplate of repetition of class names.` from doc.

Answer (score 0):

You must reference the variables correctly. Use

```
Variables.int1 = 1;
Variables.int2 = 10;
```

since they're static, or if you want to create instances of them, remove their static modifiers, then use;

```
Variables v = new Variables();
v.int1 = 1;
v.int2 = 10;
```